# Instantiate type-parametrized class at runtime with default constructor

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to instantiate a new object with the following classes:

```
class Test[T : ClassTag](val value : T) extends Serializable

private object Test {
  private var testClass : Class[_] = _

  def setTestClass(test : Class[_]) : Unit = {
    testClass = test
  }

  def apply[T : ClassTag](value : T) : Test[T] = {
    testClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(value).asInstanceOf[Test[T]]
  }
}

class Subtest[T : ClassTag](
    override val value : T, 
    val additional : Integer
) extends Test[T](value)
```

I set the test-class with `setTestClass` somewhere, that has been loaded with `Class.forName` from a string. Let say it is `"Subtest"`. I wish to instantiate a new `Subtest[String]` with - for example the following code:

```
Test("my random string") // It should return a new Subtest[String]
```

The problem is that `newInstance` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`. I've checked the `parameterTypes` of the `Constructor`, and there are two parameter types:

- class java.lang.Object
- interface scala.reflect.ClassTag

Okay. How to supply the ClassTag? What is the problem here?
Is there a better approach, workaround for this?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use reflection? Or do you "just" want to create an instance of `Test` for which you don't know the type `T` statically?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but if the constructor needs two arguments you can provide them using `.newInstance(arg1, arg2)` since this method takes a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `T: ClassTag` syntax is called a *context bound*.  It is syntactic sugar for an implicit parameter of type `ClassTag[T]`.  In other words, the following class signatures are equivalent:

```
class Test[T : ClassTag](val value : T)
class Test[T](val value: T)(implicit val ev: ClassTag[T])
```

So the constructor you're looking for expects another parameter.  When using the context-bound syntax, you can always use the `implicitly` to get the desired parameter (which is guaranteed to exist because of the semantics of the context bound).  Alternatively, you can use the `classTag` operator to directly get an instance of `ClassTag[T]` when you know it is available.

Another detail is that when using a type parameter in an object like this, it needs to be an `AnyRef`.

So your `apply` method might look like:

```
def apply[T <: AnyRef : ClassTag](value : T) : Test[T] = {
    testClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance(value, classTag[T]).asInstanceOf[Test[T]]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you were right, it needs to have an upper bound to AnyRef. It seems I have to set AnyRef to the upper bound of T everywhere? Is that correct?